# Mass effect 3 Can you accidentally cheat on someone after romance?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect, mass-effect-series

I romanced Kaidan,but talked to everyone afterwards at the citadel. I rejected Diana, but Kaidan said we were gonna have another date but I didn't see him anywhere. So did I ruin the romance by talking to Liara or something? Edit: I locked into kaidan btw, does that still mean I can cheat on him by accident?

Answer (score 1):

You can, as I recall, abort any romantic chain but it takes a conversation where you break up first (by insistence of the new romance option).  Liara has an exception to this in the shadow broker dlc in the series but does not impact your choices in ME2.

Much of the dialog in 3 is meant to hint at what will happen after the game ends.  I believe this dialog is part of that.  It's an artistic tool to get you more heavily invested in the characters, as well as "feel" the ending more.

Comment: I locked into Kaidan got the trophy and all, am I still able to cheat on him accidentally just by being nice to people?

Comment: The conversation options that lead to "cheating" are pretty explicitly more than "being nice".

Comment: Yeahhh, typically one doesn't start telling someone like Miranda how they appreciate how they're as smart as they are sexy, and that's the general tone of the conversations with her.  All of the characters are pretty obvious about the intent of the dialog.  In ME2 it's extra obvious of course.  3 assumes that all relationships are pretty clear unless you are picking up a new one, but they're all obvious about it, and all of the characters will bring up ME2 relationships you may have had with them.